# KNN with high-variance data

Tags: scikit-learn, pandas, k-nn, mathematics, variance

KNN doesn't work well with high-variance data, so how should I fit my data?

Here is an example of what the data looks like:

[image: Scatter]

Comment: What do you mean with "data that has high variance"? Variance and bias typically refers to the model itself. Also, why are you saying that KNN doesn't work well with high-variance data?

Comment: What are you trying to predict? If it's y using only x, it's clear that it's not going to work very well for high values of x.